# Why is the best function time out of a group of totals less than the last function call?

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, benchmarking, timing

I am writing 3 different functions:

The first measures the time it takes to run a function x amount of times

The second measures the time each call takes and returns the best

The third returns the best time from a number of repetitions to the first function call.

However in the results I get back from the last function, the "best" out of all the runs of total is a longer time, than the last call of total.

This seems weird to me since I would think the "best" would be the lowest out of any calls made...

I am running this in Pycharm on a Manjaro Linux OS.  Python 3.7

```
"""
Homegrown timing tools for function calls.
Does total time, best of time, and best of totals time
"""

import time, sys
timer = time.process_time if sys.platform == 'win' else time.time

def total(reps, func, *args, **kwargs):
    repslist = list(range(reps))
    start = timer()
    for i in repslist:
        ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
    elapsed = timer() - start
    return (elapsed, ret)

print(total(40, pow, 2, 50))

def bestof(reps, func, *args, **kwargs):
    best = 2 ** 32
    repslist = list(range(reps))
    for i in repslist:
        start = timer()
        ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
        elapsed = timer() - start
        #print('elapsed', elapsed)
        if elapsed < best:
            best = elapsed
            #print('best', best)
    return (best, ret)

print(bestof(40, pow, 2, 50))

def bestoftotal(reps1, reps2, func, *args, **kwargs):
    return bestof(reps1, total, reps2, func, *args, **kwargs)

print(bestoftotal(50, 40, pow, 2, 50))
```

This is the result I get:

```
(1.6689300537109375e-05, 1125899906842624)
(2.384185791015625e-07, 1125899906842624)
(1.5974044799804688e-05, (1.5020370483398438e-05, 1125899906842624))
```

However, the last call doesn't seem correct to me since the leftmost value is the "best" time out of all the totals, and the right is the total of the last call along with the value the pow functions returned.  Wouldn't the last call here be the best then???  Or is that call not included in the bestof function??

Comment: Small sidenote tip: just use `time.perf_counter()`

Comment: Switched it up but still getting the same result....  I wonder if its because of the time it takes to call and then return the results from bestof...

Comment: Im guessing that since bestof() calls total, and inside total the list(range(reps)) and print functions are outside the time measurement, that the measured time of bestof() is always going to be longer than any call to total()... but if someone could verify that could be great!  Thanks

Comment: Why can’t you check your theory?

Comment: Good point.... I will check later to see if I can check each function timing somehow...